# How do clan perks affect the level of donated troops?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Let's say your clan is at least level 5, which gives them a perk that increases the level of donated troops, and the troops that was donated is of the maximum level possible for that troop (ie. a Level 7 Giant), what would happen to its level?

Would it:

1. Become level "8" (since Level 5's perk only increases the troop by 1 level) or,
2. Stay at the maximum Level 7 (for the case of a giant)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The troop would just stay at it's current level. A level 6 giant and level 7 giant would become the same troop when donated in that clan.

Comment: Since clan perks have been in-game for only a couple of days, it's impossible for any clans to be currently at level 5, so no one can verify this. Do you have any sources for this behavior?

Comment: i'd like to have some sources for that.

Answer (score 3):

I am in a level 5 clan and when you donate maxed troops they stay the same level. But if you donate a level 4 dragon it becomes level 5 when its donated.

Comment: Does this include normal donations or only war donations?

Comment: it includes all donations.

Answer (score 2):

Supercell has said that it will actually not go to level 8 (for giants) and it will stay at the current level. But if it is a level 6 giant it will go to 7.